# How to read at least N bytes in Go

Tags: stream, io, go

How do you ensure you get at least n bytes when reading from a file in Go? The function seems to return the number of bytes you got, but I would rather just wait until more bytes are available. Is this possible without doing a bunch of manual plumbing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use io.ReadAtLeast() function: http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadAtLeast

Comment: io.ReadFull is often more convenient. (It's just a wrapper around io.ReadAtLeast anyway.)